# Перевод unsigned __int64 в биты с++

Tags: c, c++

Есть число unsigned `__int64` есть ли способ в `с/с++` получить из него строку битов?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, вообще-то unsigned __int64 и есть последовательность битов, зачем на неё какой-то union наворачивать?

Comment: >для простоты делаем класс-обёртку над таким union и функцию доступа 

охренеть простота у вас, простите уж мой французский

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например вот так:

```
unsigned __int64 num = 100; 
char buf[64]; 
_itoa_s(num, buf, 2);
cout << buf;
```

или даже так (слегка по-извращенски):

```
unsigned __int64 num = 100;

std::string st = "";
while (num) 
{
    st.insert(0, num & 1 ? "1" : "0");
    num >>= 1;
}

cout << st.c_str() << endl;
```

Comment: м, буфер на 64 элемента:) маловато будет. хотя бы 65.
во вторых, _itoa_s - это vs зависимая функция, печаль.
в третих, [_itoa_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h(v=VS.80).aspx) - принимает int. Для этих целей есть _ui64toa_s.

Comment: согласен с замечаниями, моя невнимательность

Answer (score 3):

C++: [bitset](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs101/2007/resource/www.cppreference.com/cppbitset/all.html)

C: [itoa()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/)

Answer (score 3):

Если у Вас на самом деле простая прагматичная задача установки, проверки и сброса бита по его номеру и 64 бит Вам достаточно, то можно использовать простые макросы.

Вот пример

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define SETBIT(u,n) ((u) |= ((int64_t)1<<(n)))
#define CLRBIT(u,n) ((u) &= ~((int64_t)1<<(n)))
#define TSTBIT(u,n) ((u) & ((int64_t)1<<(n)))

int
main ()
{
  uint64_t x = 0;

  SETBIT(x,0);
  SETBIT(x,1);
  SETBIT(x,62);
  SETBIT(x,63);
  printf ("%llx\n",(long long)x);
  CLRBIT(x,1);
  CLRBIT(x,62);
  printf ("%llx\n",(long long)x);
  if (!TSTBIT(x,62))
    printf("bit 62 is cleared\n");
  if (TSTBIT(x,0))
    printf("bit 0 is set\n");
  SETBIT(x,30 + 2);
  printf ("%llx\n",(long long)x);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Работает и в C и в C++.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ bits.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
c000000000000003
8000000000000001
bit 62 is cleared
bit 0 is set
8000000100000001
End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode
```

Естественно, подобным же образом (взяв или сконструировав правильную маску) можно устанавливать, сбрасывать или проверять группу бит за одну операцию.

Answer (score 1):

Почему ещё никто не опубликовал решение в compile-time с template metaprogramming?

```
 template<int n, typename s>
 struct to_binary_string_rec
 {
     typedef typename to_binary_string_rec<
             n / 2,
             typename boost::mpl::push_front<
                     s,
                     boost::mpl::char_<(n & 1) ? '1' : '0'>
             >::type
     >::type type
 };

 template<typename s>
 struct to_binary_string_rec<0, s>
 {
     typedef typename boost::mpl::if_<
             typename boost::mpl::empty<s>::type,
             boost::mpl::string<'0'>,
             s
     >::type type;
 };

 template<int n>
 struct to_binary_string
 {
     typedef typename to_binary_string_rec< n, boost::mpl::string<> >::type type;
 };

 #define TO_BINARY_STRING(n) boost::mpl::c_str< to_binary_string<n>::type >::value
```

(Сорри, не тестировал, т.к. нет boost'а под рукой.)

Comment: Да хрош пугать, "простое" решение с union пострашней будет :-)

Comment: @klopp: А где решение с union? Я что-то проспал?

Comment: @VladD просто вчера тут поступило предложение положить этот unsigned __int64 в union, union  - в класс-обертку, методом которого получать требуемую строку. Сейчас этот коммент уже удален, в качестве напоминания о нем остались два комментария к самому вопросу

Comment: @DreamChild: А, понял. Знатное извращение, непонятно только, что должно быть в union кроме этого самого `__int64`. Ну да оставим это на усмотрение фантазии автора удалённого камента.

Answer (score 1):

Нет `%b` аналога [`%x`, `%o` printf-спецификаторов](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), нет `std::bin` аналога [std::hex, std::oct iomanip](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) для двоичной системы и нет функции [`_itoa_s()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/itoa-s-i64toa-s-ui64toa-s-itow-s-i64tow-s-ui64tow-s) в стандартном C/C++.

[Можно использовать `bitset<>`](https://ideone.com/4c9nGq), чтобы unsigned целое число в "01"-строку с битами превратить:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  uint64_t n = 123;
  std::bitset<std::numeric_limits<decltype(n)>::digits> bits{n};
  std::cout << bits.to_string();
}
```

Пример:

```
$ c++ -std=c++11 *.cc && ./a.out
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111011
```