# Вывести битовое представление числа типа signed int

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int x;
scanf("%d",&x);
while (x) printf("%d",x&1),x>>=1;
    return 0;
}
```

вот мой код
вот задание: Ввести из стандартного потока число типа signed int. 
Вывести его битовое представление.
сегодня подошел к преподавателю, он сказал переделать, так как программа работает только с положительными числами. как сделать так, чтобы она работала и с отрицательными?

Comment: `signed int x;`?

Comment: она работает с отрицательными). И менять НЕ надо. Попробуйте просто ввести отрицательное число.

Comment: Ещё раз говорю: биты в неправильном порядке. https://ideone.com/lQg7hb

Comment: @Qwertiy дык речь пока не про биты идёт...

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы они были в правильном?

Comment: @pavel мне сказали нужно это сделать через массив и присвоить им элементы 1 и 0.

Comment: @qwertiy мне сказали нужно это сделать через массив и присвоить им элементы 1 и 0

Comment: Ну и причем тут было ФП?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Перевод unsigned __int64 в биты с++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/207240/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Для отрицательных не работает, поскольку знаковый бит (для 4-х байтового int это бит с номером 31) равен 1, а при сдвиге вправо он дублируется (распространяется вправо). Таким образом отрицательное число стремится не к `0`, а к `-1` (`0xffffffff`).

Поэтому заведите вспомогательную переменную -- количество напечатанных бит и проверяйте ее вместе с `x` в `while`.

Что же касается печати в "правильном" порядке, т.е. старшие разряды слева, то можно выделить вспомогательный массив и вместо `printf()` записывать биты в него, а в конце распечатать их в обратном порядке, а можно найти самый старший бит равный 1 и печатать, начиная с него. В gcc для поиска такого бита можно использовать встроенную (т.е. компилятор для каждой архитектуры имеет ее эффективную реализацию) функцию `__builtin_clz` (возвращает количество лидирующих нулей, CLZ -- Count Leading Zeros).

Например, у вас может получиться что-то в таком духе

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int x;
#if ! REVERSE && ! CLZ
  char bits[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT];
#endif

  while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
#if CLZ
    int clz = __builtin_clz(x);

    for (int i = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1 - clz; i >= 0; i--)
      printf ("%d", (x >> i) & 1);
#else
    int n_bits = 0;

    while (n_bits == 0 || (x && n_bits < sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT))
  #if REVERSE
      printf("%d", x & 1), x >>= 1, n_bits++;
  #else
    {
      bits[n_bits++] = x & 1, x >>= 1;
    }
    while (n_bits > 0)
      --n_bits, printf("%d", bits[n_bits]);
  #endif
#endif  
    puts("");
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Еще одно решение может быть основано на одинаковом битовом представлении знаковых и беззнаковых целых, но отличии в реализации побитового сдвига вправо для них. При сдвиге числа без знака старшие биты заполняются нулями.

Вот пример, для разнообразия рекурсивная реализация, т.е. вместо массива в котором запоминали биты с целью их печати в правильном порядке, будем использовать стек вызова функции.

```
void
print_bit (unsigned int x) {
  if (x) {
    print_bit (x >> 1);
    putchar('0' + (x & 1));
  }
}

void
signed_int_bits (int x) {
  if (x)
    print_bit((unsigned int)x);
  else
    putchar('0');
  puts("");
}
```

Сразу хочу отметить, что эта реализация из-за рекурсии потребует больше памяти (ну, на несколько десятков байт), нежели программа с массивом, используемым для печати бит в правильном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Если под "битовым представлением" подразумевается двоичное представление чисел в памяти компьютера, то чтобы напечатать биты от старшего разряда к младшему (big endian — как люди обычно цифры на бумаге пишут), предполагая противоположный порядок байт в памяти (little endian — как на Intel x86 процессорах):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void print_bits(const char* little_endian_memory, size_t size)
{
  for (size_t i = size; i--> 0; ) {
    const unsigned char byte = little_endian_memory[i];
    for (size_t n = CHAR_BIT; n--> 0; )
      putchar(byte & (1u << n) ? '1' : '0');
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int x = -1;
  print_bits((const char*)&x, sizeof x);
}
```

[Пример вывода](https://ideone.com/wsBSsE) на моей машине ([дополнительный код](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)):

```
$ cc -std=c99 *.c && ./a.out
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Если под "битовым представлением" подразумевается, как значение числа в двоичной системе можно записать (независимо от того как в компьютере число представлено):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void print_binary_unsigned(unsigned int x)
{
  if (x) {
    if (x >> 1)
      print_binary_unsigned(x >> 1);
    putchar(x & 1 ? '1' : '0');
  }
  else {
    putchar('0');
  }
}

static void print_binary(int x)
{
  if (x < 0) {
    putchar('-');
    return print_binary_unsigned(-(unsigned int)x);
  }
  return print_binary_unsigned(x);
}


int main(void)
{
  int x = -1;
  print_binary(x);
}
```

В этом случае, [вывод `-1`](https://ideone.com/gEbFeX).

`print_binary_unsigned(-(unsigned int)x);` дважды к `unsigned` приводит, чтобы поддерживать `x == INT_MIN` значение.

Итеративный вариант, который пишет в массив ("01"-строку) по одному биту от младшего к старшему, а затем записанные биты по месту в обращаются (в обратном порядке пишутся) с помощью `reverse()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

static void reverse(char* buf, size_t size)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size/2; ++i) {
    // swap i <-> (size - i - 1)
    char temp = buf[i];
    buf[i] = buf[size - i - 1];
    buf[size - i - 1] = temp;
  }
}


static int to_binary_unsigned(unsigned int x, char* buf, size_t size)
{
  if (!buf || size < 2)
    return -1; // error

  buf[0] = '\0';
  size_t i = 1;
  for ( ; i < size; ++i) {
    buf[i] = "01"[x & 1];
    x >>= 1;
    if (x == 0)
      break;
  }
  if (i == size)
    return -1; // error
  reverse(buf, i + 1);
  return 0; // success
}

static int to_binary(int x, char* buf, size_t size)
{
  if (x < 0) {
    if (buf && size > 2)
      *buf = '-'; // write sign
    else
      return -1; // error
    return to_binary_unsigned(-(unsigned int)x, buf+1, size-1);
  }
  return to_binary_unsigned(x, buf, size);
}

int main(void)
{
  int x = -1;
  char buf[2 + CHAR_BIT * sizeof x]; // sign + null + binary digits
  to_binary(x, buf, sizeof buf);
  puts(buf);
}
```

Вывод [тот же](https://ideone.com/d34jIP).